# What non-destructive alternatives exist to class vectors in c

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm using a vector to hold pointers to a class.

```
class fooContainer{
private:
    vector <Foo *> foos;
public:
    void processFoo(int fooIndex);
};
```

The problem I face is that `pop_back()` drops the element, I only want to remove it from the vector but not touch the object in question.  I also need to remove all elements from a vector in preparation for restarting the main cycle (but keeping the same vector, which is a class attribute).

I need a structure that has dynamic sizing but does not copy or delete its elements, being content to hold  pointers to them.

Is there a better alternative structure, or am I using them all wrong?

Comment: you should consider using std::list instead ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/ ). You can delete specific pointers with the remove() function.  For restarting your main cyclce, you should provide a erase() function to your class resetting the stored vector/list/whatever you chose last.

Comment: @Najzero er, why would you use `std::list`? All that's going to do is wreck your performance. For what purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vector does copy and destroy its contents, but in your case the content is pointer to object and not the object.
The specific pointer to the object will be destroyed, but other pointers to that object, and the object itself, won't be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

What you have does exactly that. The object elements in the vector point to won't be destroyed unless you explicitly `delete` them.

Alternatively, if you want to use the same pointers in multiple places with shared ownership, I suggest using `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

`pop` doesn't "drop" the element, it just removes it from the vector. As your vector contains pointers, you are responsible for deleting them appropriately.

Vector does exactly what you ask for.

To remove the elements, just call `vector.clear()`

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/pop_back/ suggests that the object is destroyed "This calls the removed element's destructor."

Comment: @user314159 and the element is a pointer. The pointer is "destroyed", whatever it points to is left intact.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Though I guess a `vector <Foo>` would have that functionality.

Comment: @user314159 correct. In that case, all the `Foo`s' destructors will be called.

Comment: Actually, this answer is wrong, as the object _is_ indeed destroyed.

Comment: Where did I says otherwise? What does the standard say about "dropping" the object? It is obvious from context that by 'dropping' the OP means that the element which the pointer points to is destroyed, which is NOT true. Additional, the 'element' mentioned in the question is obviously not the pointer but the object it points to, so indeed it is just removed, not destroyed.
Therefore, my answer is perfectly correct :) thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to get a copy of your pointer from your vector, then you can use `Foo* pfoo = v[0]`  or the `at(index)` function for checked access.

Also you want to clear all your pointers, you can loop through them and delete them all and call `v.clear()` to remove all elements.

If you want a vector that already does the deleting of pointers for you correctly, use a `boost::vector_ptr`